# Setting environment variable at runtime in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have running rails application. I cannot restart the server.

I have an environment variable that I need to change. I tried to do it through the `rails console`

```
ENV['SCORE'] = "123"
```

It updates variable for the current `rails c` session:

```
ENV['SCORE']
=> "123"
```

But has no effect on the variable that application is using.

Is there a way to permanently change environment variable at runtime?

Comment: Your rails server and your rails console are two separate processes. Objects are not shared between them and `ENV` is no exception.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan! That makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to share data between processes you typically use some kind of storage. In this situation, an in-memory key/value storage like Redis (http://redis.io/) seems optimal for your use case.

Install and run Redis, then put the gem in your Gemfile.

```
gem "redis"
```

In your code connect to the database

```
require "redis"

client = Redis.new
client.set("score", 123)

client.get("score")
# => "123"

client.incr("score")
# => "124"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create an initializer with that code

```
ENV['SCORE'] = "123"
```

the value will persist.

Comment: I will need to restart my server then. I am wondering if there is solution for running application?

Comment: Modifying an environment variable in one server thread won't change it for others.